# Memory allocation error calling midiInOpen with NAudio library

Tags: c#, midi, naudio

i'm trying to write a program that detects how many times a person hits a drum from the midi output of an electronic drumkit. I am using a NAudio to handle this. When i try to select a midi input i am being told that there has been a 'memory allocation error calling midiInOpen', i've had a look around and can't seem to find any resources that could explain my problem.
My midi device is definitely being recognised, at the moment i'm using a Yamaha piaggero NP-11 keyboard for the midi input.

The actual error is on line 25 where i'm adding the device:

```
midiIn = new MidiIn(0);
```

Here is my code that i'm using:

```
class Program
{
    public MidiIn midiIn;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.MainRun();
    }

    void MainRun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetMidiInDevices()[0]); // This is just to check that a midi device is actually plugged in.

        midiIn = new MidiIn(0); // <-- THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR 
        midiIn.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MidiInMessageEventArgs>(midiIn_MessageReceived);
    }

    public string[] GetMidiInDevices()
    {
        string[] returnDevices = new string[MidiIn.NumberOfDevices];

        for (int device = 0; device < returnDevices.Length; device++)
            returnDevices[device] = MidiIn.DeviceInfo(device).ProductName;

        return returnDevices;
    }

    public void midiIn_MessageReceived(object sender, MidiInMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.MidiEvent != null && e.MidiEvent.CommandCode == MidiCommandCode.AutoSensing)
            return;

        if (e.MidiEvent.CommandCode == MidiCommandCode.NoteOn)
        {
            // As the Command Code is a NoteOn then we need 
            // to cast the MidiEvent to the NoteOnEvent  
            NoteOnEvent ne;
            ne = (NoteOnEvent)e.MidiEvent;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Got input!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see `midiInOpen` in your code.  Can you clarify where the error is being thrown?

Comment: Sorry Amy, it's `midiIn = new MidiIn(0);`.

Comment: Is your application compiled as 32-bit (x86)? If not, try that.

Comment: Does the NAudio demo app work for you (the MIDI in demo)? I wonder if this is an issue to do with not pinning the callback passed to `midiInOpen`.

Comment: Jeroen, i set the platform target to x86 but i still get the same error.

Mark, i'm just download the demo now i'll give it a go.

Comment: @MarkHeath I ran one of the demos and selected to try the midi in sample and got the same error, [here is a screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/f96f4a58a64cb5248ba3fbdc815fc57c.png).

Comment: does it affect all MIDI in ports or just that particular device?

Comment: Mark, i'm using a Midi to USB cable which works with other midi programs

Answer (score 1):

**You may simply have another program or process running that's using that MIDI device.**

That can trigger the same exception on the same line of code.

It's unfortunate that error message provides no help.

Answer (score 1):

Understand that this is an old thread, but someone may find it useful.

You will likely find that this will work first time after a PC reboot, but run it again and it will fail. My understanding is that the handle is not being released properly, so Windows thinks that the device is still in use. I suspect that the interop interface that NAudio uses to interact with Windows MIDI handlers cannot tell the difference and just fails.

Make sure that you always release resources that are allocated - or reboot your PC!

Before your application exits, execute:

```
midiIn?.Stop();
midiIn?.Dispose();
midiIn = null;
```